# Ngrx "Observable" vs Ng Observable

Tags: javascript, html, angular, rxjs, ngrx

I am implementing `ngrx` to existing web application and I asked myself the question is there a difference between the normal `RxJs` Observable and the return value of my `store.select()` function? And if there is a difference, can I convert my `ngrx` store value into a normal observable?

If I log both in the console I'm getting these two different descriptions:

- the first log is the ngrx store value
- the second one is the normal observable

[Ngrx Observable vs Ng Observable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpDPk.png)

Thanks for your Help!! :)

Comment: No my problem is that i refactoring a function that used a observable and now i want to use my state variable which i thought is also a observable, but with the store.select method it doesnt work. Only with observable for example created with "of"

Comment: Then post the code of what really seems to be a problem. State indeed is a observable. You're probably just doing something else wrong.

Comment: Ive posted another answer with 2 snippets

Comment: According to the docs, `select` does return an observable for each overload indeed. You probably have some error with your store https://ngrx.io/api/store/select

Comment: If you want to add new code, expand your question.